# Example of declaring subcomponent in module annotation @Module(subcomponents = ...)

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

What is the use case of declaring `subcomponent` in dagger `module annotation`?. e.g.

```
@Module(subcomponents = ChildComponent.class)
public class ModuleB
```

I have read the documentation, but couldn't find any example of usage.

```
Any {@link Subcomponent}- or {@code @ProductionSubcomponent}-annotated classes which should be
   * children of the component in which this module is installed. A subcomponent may be listed in
   * more than one module in a component.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Dagger subcomponents declared in a module and not in the parent component directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908839/why-are-dagger-subcomponents-declared-in-a-module-and-not-in-the-parent-componen)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Subcomponent classes that should be dependent on Component that your module is child of.

I have component `A` with module `ModuleA` and component `B`. If you specify `subcomponents = B.class` inside `ModuleA`, then dagger will not compile giving

```
error: A doesn't have a @Subcomponent.Builder, which is required when used with @Module.subcomponents
@Module(subcomponents = {B.class})
^
```

unless component `B` is subcomponent of `A`.

Comment: Yup. But dependencies get resolved? If it is same as subcomponents, what benefits  we get using this syntax?

Comment: I think it is there just for verification