# Why are Dagger subcomponents declared in a module and not in the parent component directly?

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Why is the `subcomponents =` attribute set on a module of a component and not on the component directly? This doesn't seem very intuitive to me so I guess there must be a reason.

```
@Component(modules = ExampleModule.class)
public interface AppComponent 

@Module(subcomponents = ActivityComponent.class)
public abstract class ExampleModule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sense, it makes more sense for subcomponents to be on modules: They're private implementation details that are not necessarily exposed publicly, and ones that *are* exposed can still be listed as builder methods on the component directly. For comparison's sake, you also cannot define `@Provides` or `@Binds` methods directly on components; those also affect the implementation details of the component and are not necessarily visible publicly.

However, your point stands; as of April 29, 2019, this is [an open and triaged issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1463) (#1463), filed by Google contributor David P. Baker.

> We see a pattern of people creating otherwise empty modules just to add subcomponents to components:
>
> [...]
>
> Propose adding `subcomponents` to `dagger.Component`, `dagger.Subcomponent`, `dagger.producers.ProductionComponent`, and `dagger.producers.ProductionSubcomponent`.
>
> This would simplify these cases conceptually and reduce boilerplate because there is no need for an empty module.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is it common to create an empty module just to declare the subcomponent? Or would you generally use an existing module.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Entirely your choice, and you can also use [`@Module(includes={...})`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43769365/1426891) for this. I haven't often seen it on otherwise-empty modules, but that's usually because I've seen each `@Component` get its own adjacent `@Module` for utility bindings and so there's already a convenient file created. I wouldn't hesitate to put it on an otherwise-empty module if nothing else belonged there.